# UDP File transfer in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, runtime-error, runtime

I’m working on a socket programming thing for implementing a file transfer through UDP in C. Both the server and the client codes execute without reporting any errors: when I run the codes, both sockets are created and bound, and I’m prompted to input file name on client side. But after I enter it, nothing else happens.  Both sides stay blank, whereas I’m supposed to get a "file name received" output on server side and then a prompt to enter an encryption key.  I’m not getting that, and I’m not sure why. I tried several iterations of code and even tried code suggestions online, but I had no luck.  What is the problem?

Here’s the server code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SA struct sockaddr
#define PORT 12345
#define SIZE 256
#define EMP "the file does not exist"

char encrypt(char c, char k){

    return c ^ k;
}

int sendfl(FILE *fp, char *buff, int l, char k){

    int i, len;

    if(fp == NULL){

        strcpy(buff, EMP);
        len = strlen(EMP);
        buff[l] = EOF;

        for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
            buff[i] = encrypt(buff[i], k);
            return 1;
    }

    char c1, c2;

    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        c1 = fgetc(fp);
        c2 = encrypt(c1, k);
            buff[i] = c2;
    if(c1 == EOF)
        return 1;
    }

        return 0;

}

int main(){

    int sockid, len, e, n;
    char key;
    char flname[SIZE];
    char buff[SIZE];    
    FILE *fp;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    len = sizeof(servaddr);

    sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sockid < 0){
        perror("failed to create socket");
            exit(0);
    }
    printf("socket created! \n");

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    e = bind(sockid, (SA*)&servaddr, len);
    if(e == -1){
        perror("failed to bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("bind successful, \n");

    while (1) {

        printf("waiting for file name... \n");

        bzero(flname, SIZE);

        n = recvfrom(sockid, flname, sizeof(flname), 0, (SA*)&servaddr, &len);
        printf("file name recieved \t%s\n", flname);

        fp = fopen(flname, "r");
        if(fp == NULL){
            perror("failed to open file");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("file opened...");

        printf("enter encryption key \t");
        scanf("%c\n", &key);

        while (1) {

            if(sendfl(fp, buff, SIZE, key)){
                sendto(sockid, buff, SIZE, 0, (SA*)&servaddr, len);
                break;
            }

             sendto(sockid, buff, SIZE, 0, (SA*)&servaddr, len);
             bzero(buff, SIZE);
        }

        if(fp != NULL)
        fclose(fp);
         }

    return 0;
}
```

Here’s the client code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SA struct sockaddr
#define PORT 12345
#define IPA "127.0.0.1"
#define SIZE 256
#define EMP "the file does not exist"

char decrypt(char c, char k){

    return c ^ k;
}

int recfl(char *buff, int l, char k){

    int i;
    char c1, c2;

    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        c1 = buff[i];
        c2 = decrypt(c1, k);
    if(c2 == EOF)
        return 1;
    else
        printf("%c", c2);
    }

        return 0;
}

int main(){

    int sockid, len, n;
    char key;
    char flname[SIZE];
    char buff[SIZE];    
    FILE *fp;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    len = sizeof(servaddr);

    sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sockid < 0){
        perror("failed to create socket");
            exit(0);
    }
    printf("\nsocket created!\n");

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPA);

    while (1) {

        bzero(flname, SIZE);

        printf("\nenter file name:\t");
        scanf("%s\n", flname);

        sendto(sockid, flname, sizeof(flname), 0, (SA*)&servaddr, len);
        printf("\nfile recieved\n");

        printf("\nenter encryption key\t");
        scanf("%c\n", &key);

        printf("\n--------------------DATA RECIEVED--------------------\n");

        while (1) {

             bzero(buff, SIZE);
             n = recvfrom(sockid, buff, SIZE, 0, (SA*)&servaddr, &len);

            if(recfl(buff, SIZE, key)){
                
                break;
            }

        }

        printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------\n");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `scanf("%c\n", &key);` --> `scanf(" %c", &key);`  ImTheShell,  What do you think `scanf("%c\n", &key);` does?

Comment: I’m not sure what it does to be honest lol I mean... without the space that is, but yeah I’ll give it a shot with an additional space . Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Foremost you overlooked what the `\n` does in `scanf("%s\n", flname)`; here's the description from the C standard:

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the
> first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can
> be read.

So, the waiting for more input is what you perceive as *nothing else happens*.

Together with the suggestion from chux, you get one step further if you remove the `\n`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! That was the issue and after I removed the /n and adjusted the position of the scanf in the loop, the program worked flawlessly! Once again thank you all so much for the help!